# How to set styles for checkboxes in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, checkbox, twig, symfony-2.3

I have problem with checkboxes which I render by FormBuilder.

The problem is that `<input/>` is generated inside `<label></label>`. The result is the following:
[image]

I don't know what I should do to format this checkboxes to the state on the right side of the image. I check documentation and I have not found any methods which can give access to change the way how this fields are rendered.

Twig:

```
{{ form_widget(form.colors, { 'attr': {'class': 'MY-CLASS'} } ) }}
```

HTML Result:

```
<div id="template_colors" class="MY-CLASS">
    <input type="checkbox" id="template_colors_0" name="template[colors][]" value="white">
    <label for="template_colors_0">White</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="template_colors_1" name="template[colors][]" value="red">
    <label for="template_colors_1">Red</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="template_colors_2" name="template[colors][]" value="black">
    <label for="template_colors_2">Black</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the way the checkboxes are rendered in several ways. I'm going to show you the easiest one (in the example, I assume `form.colors` as the variable that holds the `choice` element):

```
<div class="" style="display: inline-block;">
{% for color in form.colors %}
   <label class="check">
   {{ form_errors(color) }}
   {{ form_widget(color) }}
   <span>{{ color.vars.label }}</span>
   </label>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

This would ouput something like:

```
<div class="" style="display: inline-block;">
    <label class="check">
    <input type="radio" id="whatever" name="whatever" required="required" value="whatever" checked="checked">
    <span>Red</span>
    </label>
    <label class="check">
    <input type="radio" id="whatever" name="whatever" required="required" value="whatever" checked="checked">
    <span>Blue</span>
    </label>                        
</div>
```

But it's just an example, you can format it the way you like. You can also pass the `class` attribute to any of them as usual.

Comment: Your solution is great, but it works only for checkbox and radio. And what about lists (when option `expanded=false` and `multiple=false`)? I tried your method but it seems that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In case you would like to have rows of four checkboxes, that will be something like:

```
{# Wrap span around checkboxes #}
{{ form_label(form.fees) }}
{{ form_errors(form.fees) }}<br>
{% for batch in form.fees|batch(4) %}
    <div class="batchRow">
        {% for option in batch %}
            <div class="yourClassName">
                {{ form_label(option) }}
                {{ form_widget(option) }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Otherwise you can get rid of the batch level.

Answer (score 0):

That's more of a CSS problem. If the inputs are inside the label you can place everything inline easily. Here is the code Bootstrap is using to do that: 
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/forms.less#L210.

If you want to use Bootstrap styles on your form you can use the [Bootstrap form theme](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme) in Symfony for that.

If you want to customize a certain field type and how it is rendered, you can create a form theme for that. Here are more details on that: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes

Hope it helps